Как правильно настроить wake on lan на asrock B550M-HDV?
Сначала я просто включил "Загрузка через встроенный сетевой адаптер" и все работало. Потом у нас пропал свет, и сейчас он не хочет запускаться через WOL. Я облазил уже все параметры в биосе, в настройках адаптера в самой Винде, не работает. Приложения лишь могут показать, в сети он или нет, но пакеты не включают ПК, хоть и доходят (Проверял с помощью программы). Что я мог упустить? Я уже пробовал и Deep Sleep включать для S4 & S5, не помогает.

Это у тебя блок питания не восстанавливает WoL после отрубания света. Фишка работает, только если ты включаешь/выключаешь комп без отрубания электричества. Если хочешь, чтобы после злых электриков комп запускался сам - лезь в настройки биоса и выставляй "включать после подачи энергии". Для WoL - только не выключать будильник.

@donRumata А что значит "Только не выключать будильник"? Как эта функция называется в биосе?

Опчатался в слове "рубильник".
